# What does using bit wise AND operator on a unsigned char object after right shifting it mean?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, byte-shifting

I'm trying to understand a snippet of code which is the following:

```
unsigned char state = portStates[portNumber];
int bitValue = (state >> 7) & 0x1;
```

It's doing a bitwise AND on the least-significant bit of
`state`, right? If it returns true (ie, that bit is set), then the
number is odd. Otherwise, it's even. Am I correct?

Thanks

Comment: it's just testing the 7th bit of the value.

Comment: Odd or even would be bit 0, not bit 7. This is simply extracting bit #7 from the state, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Yes this extracts bit 7 of state. If bit 7 is 1, returns 1. Else 0.

Comment: You don't shift an *object*. You take its *value*, and shift that *value*, and bitwise-AND the resulting *value* with `1`. Then you treat the resulting *value* as a boolean and assign it to an integer *object*.

Comment: the_naive, if code was `int bitValue = (state /128) %2;`, would that be easier to understand?

Answer (score 5):

```
int bitValue = (state >> 7) & 0x1;
```

just shifts `state` by 7 bits. Then it removes all other bits than the first one.

So converts the 7th bit (*most significant bit* in most systems where `unsigned char` is 8 bits) of your value to 0 or 1 value. It could be written as a boolean expression (using the idiomatic double negation):

```
int bitValue = !!(state & 0x80);
```

but the shifting and masking directly gives the 0 or 1 value without converting to bool.

Comment: 1 byte is always 8 bits on modern *general-purpose* CPUs. There are lots of [modern stuff where it need not be true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755034/md5-implementation-for-non-byte-addressable-arch).

Comment: I may delete that last bit, that's overanswering, just to say: "don't do it". I had that 1 byte wasn't always 8 bits but couldn't find that reference. Well, adding & 0x1 doesn't hurt.

Comment: well, you could add that generally this is the MSB (not the LSB as OP thought) ;)

Comment: Wouldn't `bitvalue = state > 127 ? 1 : 0;` be a lot more readable -- and let the compiler decide how to optimize?

Comment: or `!!(state > 127)` :) in that particular case yes. I don't like ternary that yield bools that much :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `state > 127 ? 1 : 0` differs in functionality from `(state >> 7) & 0x1` on exceptionally cases when `CHAR_BIT > 8`.

Comment: @chux: oh yes, that's why I had removed my edit on `state >> 7` (without masking). I'm not touching those formulas again.

Comment: @chux If `CHAR_BIT` was not *defined* as `8`, then `(state >> 7)` and `(state & 0x80)` would no longer work either? No?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Why not?  If `CHAR_BIT == 9`, then `(state >> 7) & 0x1;` would still report bit 7.  It would not be the _most significant bit_, yet that was not OP's posted goal.

Comment: @chux If `CHAR_BIT = 9`, the `unsigned char` would have `9` bytes and neither of the tests would fill their intended purposes of testing the MSB (incorrectly written as LSB in the question).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OP post does not appear to seek the MSB to me.  It looks like OP thought (incorrectly) the code was testing for odd/evenness by testing the LSB.  IAC, OP title seeks to understand want is happening - well answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49894808/2410359).

Comment: @chux If that be the case, and he just be wanting bit-7 irrespective of the size of *unsigned char*, then ye be right -- otherwise a change in `CHAR_BIT` would render any fixed-bit number test wrong as well. But `CHAR_BIT != 8` be not sticking with the code...

Answer (score 1):

(state>>7) returns the value generated by shifting the unsigned char "state" by 7 bits, adding leading zeros. Performing the and operation with one now gives the value of seventh bit in state.

That is, bitValue is 1 iff the seventh bit of state (from the right) is 1, or in other words bitValue is 1 iff state >= 128.

Comment: Right, Chux! Edited the answer.